# Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<T>

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function in typescript that in theory should update all keys in a object and add extra text to them:

```
interface Type {
  [key: string]: string;
}

function changeKeys<T extends Type>(obj: T) {
  let result: Partial<T> = {};

  if (!Array.isArray(obj)) {
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      result[key + "-updated"] = val;
    }
  }

  return result as T;
}
```

Because I used a for of loop I needed to create a partial. But I get this error from typescript when I try to compile the code: `Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<T>'.` Now the partial is defined as a object and I am even checking if the passed in generic isnt a array so I dont get the error then - index type = indexing a array? What would be the appropriate solution and explanation to this error in this specific case?

Comment: The expression `key + "-updated"` has type `string`. It's worth noting that your type annotations don't make any sense because you're returning an object with a completely different set of keys than the input type `T` and suggesting that such an object is a `Partial<T>` is highly misleading.

Comment: Why is this generic at all and not just `function changeKeys(obj: Type) {...}`?  With a generic function, you can call `changeKeys({a: ""})` and the compiler will infer that `T` is `{a: string}`.  A value of type `{a: string}` is not known to have a key named `"a-updated"` and is not known to have a string index signature, so you can't set its `key + "-updated"` property.

Comment: Aha! I am dumb - can you post your comment as a answer or should I delete this post alltogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'd do, you don't need to use Partial at all:

```
type Type = Record<string, string>;

function changeKeys(obj: Type) {
  const result: Type = {};
  if (!Array.isArray(obj)) {
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      result[`${key}-updated`] = val;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const test = {
  a: "test",
};

console.log(changeKeys(test));
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oCUIGMD2AnAJgHgGdgsBLAOwHMAaKI0ygPgG4AoFgMwFcy1gSMyUNAAsAhpQgBpCCAIAKDACMAVgC5Y8AJRQA3iyhCBRKFggFOAG2Dq4kKEh0BfVgZLsocgIQBBLFlEgAHQkBL7+IAoqmtp6Bgbs2B6YZMYA2gDWMjQAbqIWALpQGO4A8irowIEQZMQkZpHK0br6cQam5lapAAYAJDqZII4AtJxgOKLAEDhdhUi5Fi5xji3LbRDAnFiC7ZbArMssycaTxg4touoARCfAl1QszmxHGBYQgRYYFHIi4hRSMvIbtEmEA